# wrong schema while reading csv file as a dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

trying to read a csv file into a dataframe
simple code

```
df = spark.read.csv("1.csv")
```

i got

```
    df.printSchema()
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
```

also i try this

```
db = spark.read.csv("1.csv", header=True, inferSchema= "True")
db.printSchema()
root
 |--                   id                  |                      date                      |                              cases                               |                      country                      |                       deaths                       |   cities   |    per_cap     |
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently, your line seperator is a pipe `|`.

try:

```py
db = spark.read.csv("1.csv", sep='|', header=True, inferSchema= "True")

for col in db.columns:
    db = db.withColumnRenamed(col, col.strip())
```

Comment: hey Steven it's works but when i select columns i got this euro cannot resolve '`date`' given input columns

Comment: @ben because your schema is very weird. It is not just `date`, it's `________date________`  with a lot of spaces. I edit my code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should create your own schema.
using scala :

```
val schemaExpected = new StructType()
.add("id" , StringType , nullable = true)
.add("date" , DateType, nullable = true)
...
.add(deaths , IntegerType, nullable = true)
```

then you can read your DataFrame:

```
val db = spark.read.option("header","true").schema(schemaExpected).csv("1.csv")
```